# replacing polygons in maya scene in pyhton

Tags: python, maya

this code makes a list of all selected objects in the scene then I am trying to access each polygon in the list and replace it with a polycube but i keep getting this error:

## Error: TypeError: file  line 81: Object 0 is invalid

sel = cmds.ls(selection=True)
print (sel)

```
    for i in range(len(sel)-1):
      x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2 = cmds.exactWorldBoundingBox(i, calculateExactly=True)
      cube = cmds.polyCube()[0]  #this is line 81
      cmds.move(x1, '%s.f[5]' % cube, x=True)
      cmds.move(y1, '%s.f[3]' % cube, y=True)
      cmds.move(z1, '%s.f[2]' % cube, z=True)
      cmds.move(x2, '%s.f[4]' % cube, x=True)
      cmds.move(y2, '%s.f[1]' % cube, y=True)
      cmds.move(z2, '%s.f[0]' % cube, z=True)
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`i` is a number since `range()` returns integers, but `cmds.exactWorld...` expects a name. So this should work:

```
for i in sel:
  x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2 = cmds.exactWorldBoundingBox(i,calculateExactly=True)
  ....
```